# How to create real-time push notifications from Telegram Chats to Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I am new to Telegram development and am looking for a way to push real-time notifications from a current group that I am in to my own c# Web API. I was looking at the API docs, but confused about where should i start, Bot or Telegram APIs? Are there any existing projects that show such integration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be achieved using Telegram Bot:

1. Create a Telegram Bot by contacting [@BotFather](https://telegram.me/BotFather) bot in telegram.
2. Set a Web-Hook, so that any updates that @YourBot receives are
   transmitted by telegram via URL that you provide. It should be a
   secured one (HTTPS). You may also use polling. It is all described
   here: [Telegram Bot Api - getting updates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates)
3. Now if you add @YourBot to your Group, it will only receive/transmit your
   commands (messages that start with '/'). If you want him to
   receive/transmit all messages you have to turn off @YourBot's
   privacy mode. It is also configured via [@BotFather](https://telegram.me/BotFather).